# Using onclick outside the HTML namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, xhtml

In XHTML, can `onclick` be used on elements outside the HTML namespace? On the code below, myFunction() fires when `<p>` is clicked but not when `<t:div>` is clicked. Can it be made to?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:t="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<head><title>Sandbox</title></head>

<body>
<p     onclick="myFunction()">HTML p</p>
<t:div onclick="myFunction()">TEI div</t:div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    (alert("Hello World"));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code shown [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NIA1SQ7cSDiKdzgXDZ68?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl - Thought the same initially (tested on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJXjoK) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qg6ovqqc/) too). However, I felt there might have been some scoop to it... and so, when tested on the local machine by saving the file as `.xhtml`, the behavior in question does actually come to the fore.

Comment: @JPM are you allowed to add `id` to the custom tags?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena, not easily. I think the problem is that onclick just doesn’t have meaning outside the HTML namespace. It’s not built-in so to speak. But maybe there is a way to invoke it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `onclick` or other [event handler content attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#ref-for-event-handler-content-event-handler-content-attribute-3) on elements that are not HTML Elements, but you can attach an event listener in JavaScript. For example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:t="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <head><title>Sandbox</title></head>

  <body>
    <p onclick="myFunction()">HTML p</p>
    <t:div>TEI div</t:div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        (alert("Hello World"));
      }
      document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0", "div")[0]
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, right, @Alohci, that’s what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do  you need the full namespace here? You can't do with just `'t'`?

Comment: @MrLister - Yes, you do need the full namespace. The getElementsByTagNameNS method wouldn't know how to resolve 't' to the namespace. But you can easily try this for yourself. Just create a local file with a .xhtml extension with the content from this answer and open it in your browser.

Comment: @mrlister, if the question was meant for me: yes in this application, I need real namespaces. I can't use pseudo ones.

Comment: @JPM Oh, I just wanted some clarification on what value you could use in the ...NS call.